# Component scan a class for HandlerExceptionResolver

Tags: java, spring, component-scan, handlerexceptionresolver

I have a class for HandlerExceptionResolver

```
@Service
public class GlobalHandlerExceptionResolver implements HandlerExceptionResolver{

    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp,Object handler, Exception ex){
        return new ModelAndView("/error", "message","UH OH!!!!");
    }


}
```

I was told that the package needs to be component scanned, how do I do that?

Comment: That depends on how you setup Spring. Is it Spring Boot with Annotations? Regular Spring with some XML configuration? Something else? Did you try searching the web for component scan, i.e. *did you do your **research**?*

Comment: @greywolf18 check which package contains spring beans, for that class add 
 "@ComponentScan"

Comment: @JosePraveen how do I tell which packages contain spring beans? is it the imports?

Comment: Please go through [`@ComponentScan`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#value--)